# How to Get one from same value in different column in MySQL table using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, fetch

I have this in my `page_views` table

```
 id   cookie_id   item_id    content
======================================
1      123456   product_1     some
2      123456   product_2     some
3      654321   product_1     some
4      654321   product_2     some
5      654321   product_3     some
6      444444   product_5     some
7      222222   product_7     some
8      222222   product_2     some
9      333333   product_2     some
```

I want to make Customer also viewed boxes, all I have in my variable is the product_id of the current page. Now a new user arrives at product_2 with his/her cookie_id 333333
No I want to display him/her product boxes on customer also viewed Lebel. in this case the items with id = 1 & 5 & 7 (no duplicates) should be fetched and displayed.

```
$fetch_data = $conn->query("SELECT item_id FROM page_veiws WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM page_veiws GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(cookie_id) > 1)");
```

But it doesn't work. (Of course I do have understand `foreach` loop to display the fetched boxes), I just want the query to fetch it.

How can I achieve these goal?

Please help me?

Comment: your outer query makes no sense at all, remove it

Comment: Yah, I understand but I added that to inform for what code is needed to me. I just want sql the query.

Comment: Do you only need to fetch data from that table ?  seems like you need to join some other tables too. no ?

Comment: @Dlk Yah, exactly and I want to do this from that table

Comment: hm i can't see why id 7 is not in the mix and why line 9 as sessinon__id 333333 comes from id9

Comment: Yes, you're right id 7 is in the list now I updated but id 9 is the actual new visitor id.

Comment: I've found it hard to understand the logic. From what I can see, it would be as follows... Customer views product 2. Product 2 was also viewed by Cookies 123456, 654321 and 222222. Those cookies also viewed Products 1, 3 and 7.  Yet, you expect 1,5,7 to be returned? Why product 5? Why not product 3?

Comment: @MatBailie Because both id 1 and id 3 have the same product_id which is product_1 so id 3 is already excuted product_1 on the first row on id 1 so no need to excute duplicated 2 product_1 result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  same_cookie.item_id,
  MIN(same_cookie.id)   AS id
FROM
  page_views   AS same_product
INNER JOIN
  page_views   AS same_cookie
    ON  same_cookie.cookie_id = same_product.cookie_id
    AND same_cookie.item_id  != 'Product_2'
WHERE
      same_product.item_id    = 'Product_2'
  AND same_product.cookie_id != 333333
GROUP BY
  same_cookie.item_id
```

The where clause filters the `same_product` to be all rows that also looked at product 2, except for the current cookie (avoid showing other items the current user previously looked at).

Then, get all the products looked at by those cookies, except product 2 (avoid showing the product already being viewed).

GROUP BY to get one row per product (avoid duplicates). MIN(id) to get the first page view that looked at that product.

Returns...

```
| Product_1 | 1 |
| Product_3 | 5 |
| Product_7 | 7 |
```

If you don't want the product column, remove the first line of the SELECT clause, but keep it in the GROUP BY.

Working example : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=daa47642433bee1cbb978b929934a088

Comment: @MatBalilie Thank you so much but what about if this 333333 cookie_id is different number as it is randomly generated.

Comment: @anan This query only mentions the cookie number to avoid a user seeing their own previously viewed items. So, you just put in the current user's cookie id.

Comment: For example, if the user with cookie 654321 returned, and viewed product 2 again, you'd put that cookie id in the query. It would then return only id's 1 and 7 (excluding 5, because that was viewed by cookie 654321 itself).

Comment: I can't even thank  enough, I'm really appreciate you. Thank you so much, Your code works fine and it shines my other existed code.

Comment: @anan You're welcome.  Feel free to upvote and accept answers to your questions.